# Apple DVDPlayer screenshot-like behavior (application partial censorship)

Tags: objective-c, macos, events, handler, screenshot

I'm trying to implement Apple DVD Player-like behavior while performing screen capture with commonly used key shortcuts (⌘ + ⇧ + 3, ⌘ + ⇧ + 4 and so on).

Thing is though I've hit problem with event handling concurrency. Usually my application handles key combinations before Screen Capture utility, but sometimes (30% of cases) event is catched just after screenshot is taken, so hiding element I'm interested in is pointless.

Just to keep it clear - I'm not looking for fool-proof method of screenshot protection (I'm completely aware of endless number of ways to achieve screenshot using third party apps, terminal or external camera).

**Is it possible to increase my apps priority (on launch, while runtime, whatever) and will it help in any way?**

I'm using Cocoa Event Handler, Objective-C and Mac OS X range from 10.4 to 10.8.

Comment: Can you include the code where you set up your event handler?

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I'm using this handler: https://github.com/jaz303/JFHotkeyManager

Comment: Anyone? I couldn't find any support elsewhere, You're my only hope.